# Confirm multiple emails with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, confirmation-email

I am using rails+devise. I want the user to be able to confirm multiple e-mails (the app would send for each address a mail with a "confirm" link, and then the user have one or many confirmed mails). It is possible to confirm one with :confirmable (doc :
http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable )

I thought that i could play with

```
- (Object) resend_confirmation_instructions
```

by changing the address but this is not the best solution.
Is there a solution with devise or do i have to implement this specific functionnality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to implement this yourself. Devise has one email per account, by default.

You'd not only need to handle multiple emails, but presumably you'd also want multiple `confirmation_token`'s, along with multiples of the other database fields relating to email confirmation (find them in the devise migration file that gets generated). I don't imagine this will be a simple thing to solve with devise.

However, this sounds like a counter intuitive thing to do. Perhaps you should update your question to include the requirements of your app, and the reason why you need to get confirmation from multiple email addresses. Someone may have a solution for how to architect your app such that it doesn't need this feature.

Comment: I really need to confirm that the user has an e-mail address from a specific domain or another (@xxx.xx or @yyy.yy).
I will use token generator and send custom e-mail, devise is not the solution thank you !